# Cyclic vectors for the translation operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

Let $b\in \mathbb{R}\neq 0$, and consider the *translation operators*:
$$
\begin{align}
T_b:C(\mathbb{R}) & \rightarrow C(\mathbb{R})\\
 f &\mapsto f(\cdot + b).
\end{align}
$$
*Are there known characterization of:

- $T_b$-[*cyclic*](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cyclic_vector) functions $f$; i.e.: $\overline{\text{span}(\{T_b^n(f)\}_{n=0}^{\infty})}=C(\mathbb{R})$?*
- Functions $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\overline{\text{span}(\{T_b(f)\}_{b \in \mathbb{R}})}=C(\mathbb{R})$?

---

**What I'm looking for:**  When $C(\mathbb{R})$ is replaced by $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then, the [Wiener's Tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%27s_Tauberian_theorem) gives a characterization of functions $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ as precisely those $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for which $\hat{f}(x)\neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (where $\hat{f}$ denote the Fourier-transform of $f$).  Is there an analogous "simple" criterion/characterization in the case of translation operators on $C(\mathbb{R})$?

**Note:** I equip $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R})$ with the compact-covergence, aka. uniform convergence on compacts, aka compact-open topology *not the uniform one*

Comment: Wiener's Tauberian theorem, as usually formulated, is about the span of $\{ f(x+a): a\in\mathbb R\}$ being dense, not $\{ f(x+nb): n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling This is a good point, I made the appropriate modification to the question's formulaiton

Comment: I don't quite know how to prove this rigorously, but I think it's in fact clear that the translates of a single function can never be uniformly dense because we won't be able to approximate functions that have asymptotics incompatible with the given function.

Comment: Oh, but of course the topology on $C(\mathbb{R})$ must be the uniform on compacts one; not the uniform one (or else yes this would be essentially obvious that it won't work the reason you stated)

Comment: If $f \in H^1$ and the span of its translates is dense in $L^2$, then it is also dense in $H^1$. This follows from the core theorem, since this span is invariant under the translation semigroup whose generator has domain $H^1$. In particular, the span of the translates of such a function is dense with respect to the sup-norm.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Do you have a reference to the core theorem?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune How does your comment reconcile with the one of ChristianRemling above?

Comment: @Yemon Choi No way. If he is right I am wrong and conversely.

Comment: The core theorem is Theorem 1.9 pag. 8 of the book by B. Davies "One-parameter semigroups".

Comment: @yemonChoi Of course I am only considering $C_0(R)$, that is continuous functions vanishing at infinity.